# Android include dependency in module release

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-design-library

Given I have a module "A", that for example uses 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1' as a dependency.

Is it possible to release this module (to jitpack for example) and when the developer includes my module as a dependency, to automatically install it's own dependency ('com.android.support:design:27.1.1') without the need to make the developer add it themselves?